# Amplifying current from a photodiode

Tags: transistors, current, photodiode

i'm coming back from my previous post, to give some futher details: here's my problem:

We're going to supply power to a 4-motors drone with one/several photodiods.
Here are the characteristics:

4-motors drone: 1.8V/1.1A 
Photodiode: Vmax: 30.4V and Imax=15mA

So as you can see, the drone needs approximately 2W to fly, whereas my photodiode can supply 378mW max....

So my idea was to amplify the current out of it, by using BJT transistor ( a BJT with a Beta =100 would give me 1.5A output current if the base current is set to 15mA). Is it true to say that?

Is is possible to do what i want to do?
Any other idea? it seems that when you want to amplify the current, you usually use a current-voltage converter...

Thank you for your answers

Comment: You should call it solar cell.

Comment: Yes, your idea is quite true but what supplies 1.5 A output current ? Battery ?

Comment: People use current-voltage converter to do measurement, not to supply things power.

Comment: 1.5A is the emitter current out from the BJT that i'd like to have

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote. You have not linked to a data sheet, so "as you can see" is just wrong. We can't see any such thing. And the answer is that, yes, you can amplify the PD with a transistor - but only as long as you have a power source such as a battery to provide the extra power. What you are talking about is a perpetual motion machine.

Answer (score 4):

> So as you can see, the drone needs approximately 2W to fly, whereas my photodiode can supply 378mW max....

You are short of power. Nothing can fix that (at least, neither amplifiers, nor converters).

If you had a converter, even with 100% efficiency, you could trade voltage for current, but you could not change the power.

If you had an amplifier, that would need an external source of power.

The one way you can fix a shortage of power is storage. You still have to respect total energy, but if you charge a storage medium at low power for a long time, you can discharge it at high power for a short time. Unfortunately, any storage solution weighs something (capacitors, batteries, reversible fuel cell and gas tanks), and you're very restricted with how much extra weight a drone can carry.

A small LiPo is probably your best bet. The drone could sit on the ground sunning itself for an hour, then leap into the air for a few minutes.